# Need help creating temporary table using ADO from VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I've searched pretty extensively and found a lot of topics on this which helped me get my code to the point it is, but I'm at an impasse as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. 
I'm trying to create a temporary table so that I can pull info from a couple of other tables, drop it in, then push it out to excel. 
Right now I was just trying to create a recordset from the temporary table to check that it is being created, and I'm getting an error on the select * from temporary table line.
The error I'm getting is: error -2147217865 (800040e37) Invalid object name '#TempGetBOM'

The database platform is MS SQL Server.

EDIT: 
I updated the code to insert some data into the table to see if that would give me the object doesn't exist error.  It executed without error, so  that would indicate it exists. Then, while stepping through the code, I tried to execute the "create table" statement again, and it did error telling me the object already exists.

One thing I also found is after I create the table, if I step back in the code and run the line to check if the table exists and drop it, when I get to the create table line after that, it still says the table exits.  So obviously that check and drop if exists statement is not working as I intended.

Updated code:

```vb
'Declare variables
    Dim strSQL                      As String
    Dim strConBase                  As String
    Dim ADOcon                      As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ADOrsetA                    As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ADOcmA                      As ADODB.Command
'Initialize objects
    Set ADOcon = New ADODB.Connection
    Set ADOrsetA = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set ADOcmA = New ADODB.Command
'Ensure clean exit if there is an error
    'On Error GoTo CleanExit

'Open Connections
    strConBase = strConDriver & strConServer & strConApp & "WSID=" & Environ$("COMPUTERNAME") & ";" & strConDbTest & strConNetwork & strConTConn
    ADOcon.ConnectionString = strConBase
    ADOcon.Open
'Open Recordsets for item
    strSQL = "SELECT '" & strItem & "'," & strTblItem & ".Item_desc_1," & strTblItem & ".Item_desc_2 FROM " & strTblItem & " WHERE Item_no ='" & strItem & "'"
    Set ADOrsetA.ActiveConnection = ADOcon
    ADOrsetA.Open strSQL

'Create a temporary table to handle the intermediary work between item and BOM recordsets
    With ADOcmA
        Set .ActiveConnection = ADOcon
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('#MyTempGetBOM') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTempGetBOM"
        .Execute
        .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #MyTempGetBOM (ITEM VARCHAR(255),DESCRIP1 CHAR(255),DESCRIP2 CHAR(255), LEV INT, SEQ INT, FLAG1 CHAR(255), PRIMARYKEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,QTY_PER NUMERIC)"
        .Execute
        .CommandText = "Insert Into #MyTempGetBOM (ITEM,DESCRIP1,DESCRIP2,LEV,SEQ,FLAG1,QTY_PER) select '" & strItem & "',Item_desc_1,Item_desc_2,1,'1','o',1 FROM " & strTblItem
        .Execute
    End With

    Dim ADOrsetB As ADODB.Recordset
    Set ADOrsetB = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM #MyTempGetBOM"
    Set ADOrsetB.ActiveConnection = ADOcon
    ADOrsetB.Open strSQL
```

Comment: "SQL" isn't a database platform, so it would be useful to specify which actual platform you want to do this with.

Comment: The database platform is MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it working by changing the table name from #TempBom to MyTempBom. 
Not sure what the # is, I saw it used in some code I was trying to emulate.

Obviously, I have very little experience in SQL.

Comment: this will likely cause issues for you.  the "#" indicates a temporary table, where without it is not a temp table.  temp tables are automatically cleaned up after execution.  A real table is not.  If you had multiple users hitting the functionality to create this non temp table at the same time, unexpected behavior will occur.

Comment: That makes sense.  Right now I'm just running some tests to try to try to figure this out.  I don't understand why the temporary table doesn't work, but it does with a regular table.  I'm creating the temporary table, and I can even insert into it from another table (so that means it should exist, otherwise that would error) but when I try to create a recrodset from the temp table, it tells me it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after some more reading and searching, I decided to try a different approach to setting the recordset using the command object I created.  This worked.

I guess I don't understand the MS SQL object model well enough, but I thought the temporary table would be tied to the connection object, so that as long as I was using the same connection I could access it.  But it appears to me it's actually tied to the command object.  Is that right?

Anyways, here is the updated code that is mostly working (the drop table if object not null statement still doesn't do what I expected).  I'm sure it could be done in a better/simpler/more efficient way, but this is where I've gotten so far.

```
    'Declare variables
    Dim strSQL                      As String
    Dim strConBase                  As String
    Dim ADOcon                      As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ADOrsetA                    As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ADOcmA                      As ADODB.Command
    Dim ADOrsetB                    As ADODB.Recordset
'Initialize objects
    Set ADOcon = New ADODB.Connection
    Set ADOrsetA = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set ADOcmA = New ADODB.Command
    Set ADOrsetB = New ADODB.Recordset
'Ensure clean exit if there is an error
    'On Error GoTo CleanExit

'Open Connections
    strConBase = strConDriver & strConServer & strConApp & "WSID=" & Environ$("COMPUTERNAME") & ";" & strConDbTest & strConNetwork & strConTConn
    ADOcon.ConnectionString = strConBase
    ADOcon.Open
'Open Recordsets for item
    strSQL = "SELECT '" & strItem & "'," & strTblItem & ".Item_desc_1," & strTblItem & ".Item_desc_2 FROM " & strTblItem & " WHERE Item_no ='" & strItem & "'"
    Set ADOrsetA.ActiveConnection = ADOcon
    ADOrsetA.Open strSQL

'Create a temporary table to handle the intermediary work between item and BOM recordsets
    Set ADOrsetB.ActiveConnection = ADOcon
    With ADOcmA
        Set .ActiveConnection = ADOcon
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('#MyTempGetBOM') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTempGetBOM"
        .Execute
        .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #MyTempGetBOM (ITEM VARCHAR(255),DESCRIP1 CHAR(255),DESCRIP2 CHAR(255), LEV INT, SEQ INT, FLAG1 CHAR(255), PRIMARYKEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,QTY_PER NUMERIC)"
        .Execute
        .CommandText = "Insert Into #MyTempGetBOM (ITEM,DESCRIP1,DESCRIP2,LEV,SEQ,FLAG1,QTY_PER) select '" & strItem & "',Item_desc_1,Item_desc_2,1,'1','o',1 FROM " & strTblItem
        .Execute
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM #MyTempGetBOM"
        Set ADOrsetB = .Execute
    End With
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong here, but I can only access the temp table one time, then it seems to disappear.  I.E. in the code below, setting the first recordset works, but the second throws the "invalid object name" error for #MyTempGetBOM.  However, if I skip the line that sets the first recordset, then the second one works.  It seems like the temp table disappears after the first call to it.  `.CommandText= "SELECT * FROM #MyTempGetBOM"
            Set ADOrsetA = .Execute
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM #MyTempGetBOM"
            Set ADOrsetB = .Execute`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the SQL Server session your temporary table is created in is terminated when your procedure completes.